# PHP undefined index is defined

Tags: php, session, indexing

I'm learning how to create sessions in PHP, but got stuck in sintax problem, wich the solution i looked for everywhere but didn't find.

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['nome']);
?>
<html>
    <head><title>Finalizando uma Sessão</title></head>
    <body>
        A variável <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']?> foi finalizada.
    </body>
</html>
```

It says that the index 'nome' is undefined. I've used 'nome' to iniate and recover the session in 2 others pages.

Comment: You are unsetting it, then trying to echo it??

Comment: Just read this: [unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Comment: You've unsetted the session then you're trying to echo it, so your code (*strangely enough*), has done its job. Use `isset` to check if it's set or not, then *try* to echo it. I.e.: `if (isset($_SESSION['nome'])){ echo $_SESSION['nome']; } else{ echo "Session is not set";}`

Answer (score 1):

You use the `unset` function. That function is for unsetting a variable.
To create a session you need to do this:

`$_SESSION['nome'] = 'Msalvatori'`

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome'] = 'Msalvatori'
?>
<html>
    <head><title>Finalizando uma Sessão</title></head>
    <body>
        A variável <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']?> foi finalizada.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear about my doubt.

I want to unset the session, but then, I want to confirm that the index was unset by displaying it on my page. And if I can't use the index after it was unset, is there other way to do display the index?

Comment: Yes [`right here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388656/php-undefined-index-is-defined#comment35830940_23388656) @Msalvatori

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the undefined error message is this:

You have [`unset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)*'ted* the session name then you are trying to echo it, so your code (*strangely enough*), has done its job. Use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) to check if it's set or not, then echo it.

Look at the following, using a conditional `isset` statement.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['nome']);
?>

<html>
    <head><title>Finalizando uma Sessão</title></head>
    <body>
        A variável <?php // echo $_SESSION['nome']; 
        if (isset($_SESSION['nome'])){ 
        echo $_SESSION['nome']; 
        } else{ echo "Session is not set";} ?> foi finalizada.
    </body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to echo "Session is not set" in its place, simply do:

```
echo "\n";
```

You could also do:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['nome'])){ 
        echo $_SESSION['nome']; 
    } 

    else{ 
    $_SESSION['nome'] = "John";

        echo $_SESSION['nome'];
    }
?>
```

If coming from a POST variable, you could do:

```
<?php 
// $_POST['nome'] = "John";

$name = $_POST['nome'];

if (isset($_SESSION['nome'])){ 
echo $_SESSION['nome']; 
} else{ 

$_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
echo $_SESSION['nome'];

}
?>
```